# MYSQL Delete outliers for mulitiple products

Tags: mysql

I’m working with a large database and I’m trying to delete data outliers. I found this code from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631344/deleting-outliers-with-mysql-using-standard-deviation) and I modified it to work with my database.

```
DELETE FROM sv_condition_sw 
WHERE snow_mountain > (select * from (SELECT AVG(snow_mountain)+1.5*STDDEV(snow_mountain) 
                                  FROM sv_condition_sw 
                                  WHERE lud='2012-11-28' ) x)
AND lud='2012-11-28'
```

It works great with one exception.

I have thousands of “lud”s or products in my case. How could I delete each lud (or product) with one query?

Comment: It would be easier to answer, if you provided your database structure with relationships between the tables

Comment: Looks like you might have to write a script, since you have `lud` appear twice in your query. Otherwise you could use the `IN` clause.

Comment: user4035 - its just one table.

Comment: ktm - I tried the IN clause. That finds the avg and sttdev for all the lud included in the IN clause. I need something that looks at each lud separately and find the avg and sttdev. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try something like

```
DELETE sv_condition_sw 
FROM sv_condition_sw, 
   (SELECT AVG(snow_mountain)+1.5*STDDEV(snow_mountain) as threshold, lud
   FROM sv_condition_sw GROUP BY lud) as t
WHERE sv_condition_sw.snow_mountain > t.threshold
AND sv_condition_sw.lud=t.lud
```

This should work in MySQL as well.