# subquery with aggregate/analytic function in Hiveql

Tags: sql, hiveql

I'm wondering if this is legal:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE my_table
  SELECT field_1, field_2, 
     (SELECT STDDEV(field_from_my_table) 
      FROM my_table 
      WHERE field_from_my_table !=0)
  FROM my_table
  GROUP BY field_1;
```

So far, I haven't been able to get it to work. I get a myriad of errors depending on what I try, mostly random errors indicating illegal syntax. Eg.

```
cannot recognize input near 'SELECT' 'STDDEV'
```

This, however, does work:

```
 INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE my_table
  SELECT field_1, field_2, STDDEV(field_from_my_table) 
  FROM my_table
  GROUP BY field_1;
```

So basically, I'm just changing how I'd like to use STDDEV - nothing else is different between the version that works and the one that doesn't.

If it's not possible to do it this way, why not? If it is, what corrections do I need? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: Possibly this [Nested queries in Hive SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631259/nested-queries-in-hive-sql#13643328), this [Hive column as a subquery select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710075/hive-column-as-a-subquery-select), or this [Does Hive support Select in Select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059559/does-hive-support-select-in-select/22059792#22059792)

EDIT2: So I think the easier question might be:
this works,

```
 INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE my_table
  SELECT field_1, field_2, STDDEV(field_from_my_table) 
  FROM my_table
  GROUP BY field_1;
```

And this works (as an interactive query)

```
SELECT field_1, STDDEV(field_from_my_table) 
FROM my_table
WHERE field_from_my_table !=0
GROUP BY field_1;
```

How do I combine the two into a single table (new or old)?

Comment: What you say works doesn't, because it has multiple syntax errors.  You should also say what "doesn't work" means.  Are you getting an error?  Does it return unexpected results?

Comment: Sorry this is in Hive. Did I forget a semicolon?

Comment: Syntax errors:  `field 2`. `GROUP BY,`, `select field1, field`/group by field1`.  Your code is also missing the column list for the `insert` (which is optional but should be a best practice).

Comment: Sorry - those errors were from creating this example to post - not the source of my actual error (which is posted).

Comment: there is no `STDDEV` function in Hive. `stddev_pop` and `stddev_sample` are the only ones supported.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala that’s just not true.

Comment: atleast i don't see it in the [`documentation`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-Built-inFunctions)

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala I ran the code and it works. So assume whatever you wish. Bottom line, it's not the source of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the short answer is I did a workaround. Since I was able to run the more detailed query as an interactive one, I decided to attempt to run said query and insert into a table. Well, you get the same error. It turns out, however, that you can run the query, write it to a local file, then load from local into a new table. This gets around having to write a subquery within a query, which I think in this particular instance is not supported by Hive (or in the case where you just can't successfully write one, like me).

Exact solution to follow soon...